# Can't login to twitch using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, browser, automation, twitch

I'm working on a PowerShell script to login to twitch via Internet Explorer. I'm successful to populate Username and Password fields but Log In button remains disabled. Log In button needs to be enabled and click for successful login. Please guide me to make this work. Below is my script

```
$Url ="https://www.twitch.tv/login"
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$username="Your_User_Name"
$password="Your_Password"

$ie.Navigate($Url)

while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 }
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 

$usernamefield = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("login-username")  
$usernamefield.value = $username;

$passwordfield = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password-input")
$passwordfield.value = $password;

$loginbutton = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")[3].click()
```

[As shown in screen shot, user name and password get populated in required fields but Log In button remains disabled after running script and also doesn't click to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWQDB.png)

Comment: I tried to make the button class the same as when it is enabled, but still can't click it when automating it using PowerShell in IE. I suggest you could refer to the answer below to use [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/projects/) to automate the browser. Selenium WebDriver drives a browser natively, as a real user would so it is the closest to the real user behavior. But the powershell script you using is just set the input value and it can't simulate the user behavior so the login button can't be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input boxes appear to not actually be accepting the values. In addition to that issue, there are two login buttons. One is the "disabled" one you see and the other is shown when the input boxes are filled. The following command shows the difference in css for each.

```
$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("Button") | where {$_.textContent -eq "Log In"} | foreach {"Log In button`n";$_.outerhtml;"`n"}

Log In button

<button class="tw-block tw-c-text-inherit tw-full-height tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-pd-l-0 tw-pd-r-1 tw-tab-item" role="tab"><div class="tw-align-left tw-flex tw-flex-column tw-full-heig
ht"><div class="tw-flex-grow-0"><div class="tw-font-size-5 tw-regular">Log In</div></div><div class="tw-flex-grow-1"></div><div class="tw-flex-grow-0"><div class="tw-tabs__active-indicator" d
ata-test-selector="ACTIVE_TAB_INDICATOR"></div></div></div></button>


Log In button

<button disabled="" class="tw-align-items-center tw-align-middle tw-border-bottom-left-radius-medium tw-border-bottom-right-radius-medium tw-border-top-left-radius-medium tw-border-top-right-
radius-medium tw-core-button tw-core-button--disabled tw-core-button--primary tw-full-width tw-inline-flex tw-interactive tw-justify-content-center tw-overflow-hidden tw-relative" data-a-targ
et="passport-login-button"><div class="tw-align-items-center tw-core-button-label tw-flex tw-flex-grow-0"><div class="tw-flex-grow-0" data-a-target="tw-core-button-label-text">Log In</div></d
iv></button>
```

If we use the Selenium Powershell module, it makes it somewhat easier, though the requirement for Internet Explorer made it a bit more challenging. The following code can be used to successfully log into Twitch with Internet Explorer.

First, for the driver to work all the security zones in IE must have protected mode on or off, they have to match. This code will disable protected mode for all zones except Local Computer.

```
1..4 | foreach {
    Set-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\zones\$_\" -Name 2500 -Value 3
}
```

Now we can automate the login. The issue with finding the button by tag, is that in IE that only returns one button. By using xpath we are able to find all buttons and filter by the text.

```
Install-Module Selenium -Scope CurrentUser -Force

$Url ="https://www.twitch.tv/login"
$username="Your_User_Name"
$password="Your_Password"

$driver = Start-SeInternetExplorer -StartURL $Url

$usernamefield = $driver.FindElementById("login-username")

Send-SeKeys -Element $usernamefield -Keys $username

$passwordfield = $driver.FindElementById("password-input")

Send-SeKeys -Element $passwordfield -Keys $password

$loginbutton = $driver.FindElementsByXPath("//button")| where text -eq 'Log In' | select -last 1

$loginbutton.Click()
```

I still recommend using Chrome, Firefox, or New Edge over IE. The following code will achieve the same result in Chrome.

```
Install-Module Selenium -Scope CurrentUser -Force

$Url ="https://www.twitch.tv/login"
$username="Your_User_Name"
$password="Your_Password"

$driver = Start-SeChrome -StartURL $Url

$usernamefield = Find-SeElement -Driver $driver -Id "login-username"

Send-SeKeys -Element $usernamefield -Keys $username

$passwordfield = Find-SeElement -Driver $driver -Id "password-input"

Send-SeKeys -Element $passwordfield -Keys $password

$loginbutton = Find-SeElement -Driver $driver -By TagName "button" | where text -eq 'Log In' | select -last 1

$loginbutton.Click()
```

Comment: I've tested your code and it asks every time for the verification code sent via email or to solve the puzzle. The idea is to run this script in background to open a hidden browser window. I've two questions; first is it possible same thing with IE using selenium? and second  I guess using selenium the twitch is not taking it as a normal user and that's why asking each time for code or puzzle. Can we bypass this?

Comment: That really doesn't have anything to do with the code. Twitch requires you to verify new devices/apps. So if you complete it once in chrome on a PC, I would imagine it wouldn't require that again on that PC/browser.

https://help.twitch.tv/s/article/new-device-and-location-verification?language=en_US

Comment: Powershell Selenium module does not uses IE and in my case I've to use IE. I've found another blog here [link](https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2018/12/06/using-powershell-and-selenium-for-browser-automation/) using selenium with IE. I've modified the code and it populate user name and password. Can't click Log In button though it's enabled. I'm new to selenium can you help me to fix code to click Log In button? Then I will accept your answer

Comment: Can you use Edge?

Comment: No. I see Selenium module supports edge.

Comment: I have solved it using FindElementByXPath(). It clicks the login button. I'm not sure it it's the best approach. Thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: I've added code for Internet Explorer. I also solved it using FindElementsByXPath. Selenium supports all the major browsers AFAIK.